# Selenium leaving chrome processes open

Tags: python, selenium, memory-leaks, process

I am using selenium headless browser with chromedriver to crawl content from websites that have javascript generated code. (thus why I can't use requests)

The code runs for a good couple of hours as the amount of pages to be crawled is large, and even though every time I make use of the webbrowser object it is encompassed in a try/except/finally statement like:

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options, executable_path=chrome_driver)
t=eventlet.Timeout(15)
try:
    browser.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source,"lxml")
    row = soup.find("div",{"id":"row0"})
except:
    pass
finally:
    t.cancel()
    browser.quit()
```

there are multiple chrome processes running for hours when I check `top` or `ps`.

What is the most correct way to effectively instantiate, use and free the memory used by selenium webdriver?